# Should a control properly remove from parent object before disposing?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, dispose

Well, should I properly remove any control from the parent object before it is set to dispose? Will this cause memory leak to the parent object if it is disposed before removing it from parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disposing is all about releasing unmanaged resources while removing a reference will only ever effect the garbage collector which only deals with managed memory so no, you will not cause a memory leak in the way you are describing.

Comment: Thanks. So every time I can just dispose it directly without any need to remove it from the parent object.